# Spring Integration - SFTP File Sync - Message is not generated when file name is same but time stamp is different

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I've configured my application with a SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource. I would like a message to be received with file as the result payload whenever a new file is found (i.e. a new file name and / or time stamp). Here's what I have:

```
@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(applicationProperties.getSftpDirectory());
    CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>();
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store, "sftp"));
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(applicationProperties.getLoadFileNamePattern()));
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
    fileSynchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup="true", channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller("pollerMetadata"))
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(applicationProperties.getScheduledLoadDirectory());
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
    compositeFileFilter.addFilter(new LastModifiedFileListFilter());
    compositeFileFilter.addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store, "dailyfilesystem"));
    source.setLocalFilter(compositeFileFilter);
    source.setCountsEnabled(true);
    return source;
}
```

This works great except for the scenario where on the subsequent poll I get the same file name with a different modified time stamp. In that case, I get a null result for the message. How can I ensure that a message is generated when the time stamp is the different but the file name is the same?

Comment: Oddly enough, I seem to get an extra file (in addition to the updated file that I wish would generate a message) after SFTP. The file is the same file with .writing appended to the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your existing local copy (an old one) is busy somewhere downstream. The resource is open. And therefore an adapter can't override it.

Has been fixed recently: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4305

Comment: Thanks. Same result with 4.3.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Is there a work around or should I try I different version?

Comment: ??? We don't control an open file. We just say that we can't do that because file is busy somewhere. You should reconsider your downstream logic and close file properly to ensure that it will be overridden by a new remote content.

Comment: The file is not open at the remote source (SFTP server - a Linux machine). I confirmed with `lsof  | grep "myfilename"`

Comment: ??? The *local* file is open. We don't talk about remote. Your remote comes well, but adapter can't right it into local dir because the local file is busy

Comment: I see. Local is a Windows machine and bit harder to tell if file is open by some process. I have a Spring Batch job that processes the file. I suppose the file is not being closed properly after processing.

Comment: Sounds like that. Another opinion that you bring a fresh file from the remote to early. Consider to postpone its download from the FTP via similar `LastModifiedFileListFilter`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `LastModifiedFileListFilter`. I'm not explicitly opening the file and I'm not writing to the file. I'm just using standard Spring Batch to read and then write to a DB. Not sure why the file is being left open locally.

Comment: OK. I thought was in agreement about the local file being open but actually I get the new remote file from the server. It has the latest time stamp and the data as expected. Plus, I have the same file with `.writing` appended to the file name. But I don't get a message. So, I'm still stuck.

Comment: There is no other explanation. Your config is exactly for the `preserveTimestamp` use-case. And only the problem can be a "file is open locally". That's all

Comment: My apologies... the time stamp is updated but the file data is still the old data. Need to figure out how to close the file that I presume Spring Batch has opened.

Comment: If you have `.writing` file that means it can't be renamed to the original file. And only reason is because the target file is open.

Comment: Agreed. I'm accepting this answer. Thanks for your help.